# Eclipse project not remembering facets - affecting content assist

Tags: eclipse, jsf, primefaces

Eclipse Version: 3.7.1 (Indigo)

I am trying to provide content assist for JSF and Primefaces.

To do this I am right clicking on my project > Properties > Project Facets

I am presented with the Project Facets screen. I select:

- Dynamic Web Module 2.5
- Java 6
- Java Server Faces 2.0

I am then prompted to provide Futher Configuration. I select the src folder as part of the Build Path and provide a JSF implementation library which provides the following dependencies:

- jsf-api-2.0.3
- jsf-impl-2.0.3
- primefaces-3.4

I then click OK to return to the Project Facets screen.

I click "Apply" to apply the new Facet configuration to my web project. **The ticks then dissappear.**

I click OK to close the Project Facets screen.

When I return to this screen **the ticks are gone**.

I am fairly sure that this is the reason why my context assist for Primefaces and JSF is not working in xhtml pages. Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that this was happening because a colleague had checked in the .classpath and .project files for the Project into a SCM tool which reserved/locked the files (in my case, ClearCase).

Eclipse was not reporting the lock, so there was no explanation as to why the ticks were being lost upon clicking 'apply'.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: I am not sure why I find this funny, but for some reason the condescending Wonka meme popped into my head when I heard your colleague checked in the .classpath and .project files. :)

Comment: LOL!  Now you just need to print it out and pin it inside his cubicle!